# Проверка TextBox'ов на пустоту

Tags: c#

Использую для проверки на пустоту такой способ

На кнопку вешаю

```
foreach (var pb in Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
   if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pb.Text))
   {
      Textbox.Text = "Не всё заполнено";
   }
   else
   {
      TextBox.Text = "Всё заполнено";
   }
}
```

Но если в одном TextBox'e ничего не записано, то показывает что "Всё заполнено".

Если убрать текст из 2-ух TextBox'ов, то вываливает сообщение "Не всё заполнено"

Comment: Достаточно добавить `break;` в первую ветку `if`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, Внатуре, забыл совсем :) Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот так работает:

```
var isEmty = Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Any(x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Text));
Textbox.Text = isEmty ? "Есть пустые" : "Нет пустых";
```

Естественно должно быть использовано в начале файла:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Но это не то чтобы хорошо - каждый раз пробегать по визуальному дереву... По уму бы отделить данные от контролов и проверять в моделях. Если `WPF` используете - попробуйте осилить `MVVM`. Ну или что-то подобное из сходных паттернов, типа `MVC` на `WinForms` можно завести (но лучше все же осваивать `WPF` и `MVVM`).

Comment: Метод работает, благодарю.

Comment: А можно к этому примеру добавить ещё контролов `ComboBox`,`CheckBox` ?

Comment: Выноси в функцию, делай по аналогии. Всё можно. Но опять же, скоро все это может начать тормозить, ибо запрос к визуальному дереву не бесплатная операция.